# Saving wordcloud in R

Tags: r, caching, shiny

How to save a word-cloud in R as a variable, because its not a ggplot object. My Pain point is that I have a huge text data and I am trying to create an app on Shiny. So apparently by saving the Wordcloud, it will be very quick after second try, I am planning to save the wordcloud chart with memoise.

I Appreciate every help

Answer (score 0):

you can make an `htmlwidget` wordcloud with https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2

```
mywordcloud<-wordcloud2(data)
```

then save it with

```
saveWidget(mywordcloud, file="mywordcloud.html")
```